# Starting daemon under linux as a user with user's environment

Tags: linux, environment-variables, daemon

I am trying to configure a daemon process to run as a particular user, with that user's configuration information. I've tried
    daemon /path/to/script --user=myUser

However, when I run a sample script that simply echoes $HOME to a file, it still shows /root for the home, not /home/myUser. Is there a switch for daemon that changes to the user as if you were doing "su"?

If not, is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a switch for daemon that changes to the user as if you were
>   doing "su"?

No, there is no such switch. But you can use `su` itself:

```
daemon -- su -s/path/to/script myUser
```

or

```
daemon -- su -s/path/to/script - myUser
```

However note that this won't read myUser's configuration file (~/.daemonrc).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using crontab to invoke background tasks
the problem with crontab that it runs periodic tasks.
to avoid task duplication, I'm using pgrep

**example**: running my flask server once
server.sh

```
if [[ -z "$(pgrep flask)" ]]; then
  echo skipping
else
  # run flask server here
fi
```